# Collection: Printing the top five occurrences by reading from a file

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to read a large file. File contains `lastName, firstName` on each line. 
How would I print top 5 occurrence of lastName and top 5 occurrence of firstName?

Till now I have thought of using TreeMap. But it sorts by keys not values. What is the best collection to approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'top' ? By frequency ? alphabetical order ?

Comment: I think, that you must write your own implementation of List collection. Or try to find some libraries.

Comment: @JihedAmine By frequency,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a `Map<String, Integer>` containing the lastNames a keys, and their corresponding frequency as value. Do the same for the first names.
- populate the maps while reading the file
- Create a `List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>` containing all the entries of the map (one list for each map)
- sort these lists using a custom comparator that compares entries by their value (i.e. by frequency), in descending order
- pick the 5 first elements of the lists and extract their names

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple collections.  The first two collection records the count for first and last names.  Once you have these you can create a structure where you sort by the count and associate this with the name.